# Black inside the pickerview

Tags: ios, uipickerview

It is all black in the UIPickerView. I do not know what is happening.  I do not have warnings and errors and when I try to bring up the picker view it just shows black.  Did I do something wrong and is there a possibility that I have forgoten something.

This is my code.

```
@synthesize stillImageOutput, imagePreview, captureImage, cameraSwitch, pickerViewContainer;

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == genre)
        return [arraygenre count];

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == genre)
        return [arraygenre objectAtIndex:row];
    return 0;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;


}
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 307, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)closeButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 800, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**Update**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FrontCamera = NO;
    cameraSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    captureImage.hidden = YES;

    arraygenre = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"blue"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"yellow"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"white"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"red"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"purple"];
    [arraygenre addObject:@"Others"];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 800, 320, 261);


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self initializeCamera];
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //fetch Category Name from the array used to fill the Picker View
    NSString *categoryName= [arraygenre objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:categoryName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    UIImage *image = captureImage.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:fPath atomically:YES];

}
```

In my .h file i have

```
#define genre 0



@interface CameraSave : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {


    BOOL FrontCamera;
    BOOL haveImage;

    IBOutlet UIPickerView     *SaveTopicker;
    NSMutableArray            *arraygenre;
}
```

Comment: let check genre variable

Comment: Where are `genre` and `arraygenre` defined?

Comment: I have added my code for genre and array genre

Comment: I'm still not seeing `genre` being defined.

Comment: its defined at the top

Comment: i have defined #define genre 0 in both header and implementation

Comment: Where have you allocated and initialized the pickerView ?

Comment: The above is only all what I have written for the picker view

Comment: What do I have to add inorder to get rid of this black and have the spinning wheel again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you allocate & intialize pickerview?? and is delegate is set?

try this in viewDidLoad

```
SaveTopicker.delegate = self;
SaveTopicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:SaveTopicker];
```

for more reference check this [Tutorial1](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.in/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html), [Tutorial 2](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html)

Comment: I have Made it hide and then pop out when hitting the save button if I put the code that you have gave me it just sits in the middle the black is removed thought the positioning is bad

Comment: ok, than what is your  `pickerViewContainer`?
if it is view then put,
`[pickerViewContainer addSubview:SaveTopicker];`
an make picker frame (0,0,320,200)

Comment: I am using the tutorial [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwHIud_3LUw) to make this.  It works on the file that he gives. and download his project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49525238/HidePickerView.zip)

Comment: ok have you put picker in Xib?? if you have put than not need to allocate n you have to just link it with savetopicker, n give delegate and datasorce it..

Comment: Thanks every one who answered I was able to make it show.  It was that I did not connect the the datasource and the delegate to the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Reading",@"Music",@"Cricket",@"Movie",@"Travelling",nil];
    [hobbyPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
    -(void)buttonHobby:(id)sender
    {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        hobbyPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 216);
        pickerToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 44);
        [UIView commitAnimations];


      }
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger numRows = 5;

    return numRows;
}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [array objectAtIndex:row];

}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)componen
{
    CGFloat componentWidth = 0.0;
    componentWidth = 135.0;

    return componentWidth;
}
```

Try this code acording to your need... hope this wprks for u..

Comment: Giving a generic version of the code that the OP is using doesn't answer the question.